# Login com Ajax e PHP com redirecionamento

Tags: php, ajax, login

Olá, estou tentando fazer um login, porém estou me deparando com o seguinte, quando faz o login redireciona pra mesma div da página, em vez de ir direto pra outra página. Alguém tem uma solução?

HTML

```
 <div class="loader" style="display: none;"><img src="assets/img/loader.gif" alt="Carregando" /></div>
            <div class="mensagem-erro"></div>



        <form action="logar.php" class="form-signin" method="post" id="frmLogin">
            <p class="text-muted text-center btn-block btn btn-primary btn-rect">
               Digite seu usuário e senha


            </p>
            <input name="username"type="text" placeholder="Usuário" class="form-control" />
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha" class="form-control" />
            <button class="btn text-muted text-center btn-danger" id="btn-login" type="submit">Entrar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

AJAX

```
$(function($) {

    $('#frmLogin').submit(function() {

        // Limpando mensagem de erro
        $('div.mensagem-erro').html('');

        // Mostrando loader
        $('div.loader').show();

        // Enviando informações do formulário via AJAX
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(resposta) {

            // Se não retornado nenhum erro
            if (!resposta)
                // Redirecionando para o painel
                window.location.href = 'logar.php';
            else
            {
                // Escondendo loader
                $('div.loader').hide();

                // Exibimos a mensagem de erro
                $('div.mensagem-erro').html(resposta);
            }

        });

        // Retornando false para que o formulário não envie as informações da forma convencional
        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: Qual o código PHP, HTMl. Retorna algum erro ?

Comment: editei e coloquei :)

Comment: !resposta = false, caso seu valor seja true. Essa é a intenção ?

Comment: Acho que a melhor forma pra resolver esse erro seria redirecionar pelo código Ajax, em vez do PHP né? Mas não sei como fazer isso

Comment: Poste o código PHP, para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Amigo, o código em PHP é só um login comum não influência nada no Ajax

Comment: Você tem que ver o redirecionamento no arquivo logar.php, pois o erro não está no html e nem no ajax.

Comment: O redirecionamento no arquivo php está ok, eu redireciono com o header, normalmente